# Use Margin Auto & Flex to Align Text

Tags: html, css, sass

I have three sections, two of which may or may not have different size images depending on user input. Within those two sections are text which I want aligned even if the images are not the same height. I have assigned the sections display flex, along with the parent element of the text, and my text to margin-top: auto. To my knowledge this should work. What am I missing to accomplish this? Any guidance would be appreciated.

```css
section.wraps-section {
    text-align: center;
    padding: $section-padding-y*5 $section-padding-x $section-padding-y*3;

    header {
        padding-bottom: $base-spacing;
        h2 {
            color: $white;

            mark {
                color: $primary-color;
            }
        }
    }

    .section-body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 100px;

        @include lg-up {
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .block {

            &.content {

                .block-body {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                }

                p {
                    color: $white;
                    font-family: $tertiary-font-stack;
                    font-size: 30px;
                    margin-top: auto;
                }
            }

            &.svg {
                width: 100px;
                svg {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="wraps-section" style="<?= $bg_style ?>">
    <header>
        <h2><?= $section_title ?></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="section-body">
        <div class="block content">
            <div class="block-body">
                <img src="<?= $before_image_url ?>">
                <p><?= $before_title ?></p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="block svg">
            <?php Assets\render_svg('wrap-arrow'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="block content">
            <div class="block-body">
                <img src="<?= $after_image_url ?>">
                <p><?= $after_title ?></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-footer">
        <?php if ($cta_text && $cta_url): ?>
            <a href="<?= $cta_url ?>" class="button"><?= $cta_text ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there but you have two issues to resolve:

### 1. `align-items: center`

You've added `align-items: center` to your `.section-body`. It means that the children will be center aligned and **won't take 100%** of `.section-body`'s height.

### 2. `.block.content`

`.block.content` doesn't take 100% of the height of it's parent. To solve that, you can simply add the rule `display: flex;`

Here is an example with a simplified version of your code and with the css compiled:

```css
section.wraps-section {
  text-align: center;
}
section.wraps-section .section-body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
}
section.wraps-section .section-body .block.content {
  display: flex;
}
section.wraps-section .section-body .block.content .block-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section.wraps-section .section-body .block.content p {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="wraps-section">
  <div class="section-body">
    <div class="block content">
      <div class="block-body">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/120x150.png">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block content">
      <div class="block-body">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The scss not compiled:

```
section.wraps-section {
  text-align: center;
  
  .section-body {
    display: flex;
    // align-items: center will center the items, meaning they won't take the full height of their parent    
    // align-items: center;
    gap: 100px;
    flex-direction: row;

    .block {
      &.content {
        // By adding display: flex, you make .content the full height of it's parent
        display: flex;
        
        .block-body {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        p {
          margin-top: auto;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```